# Return page of results around User's best score

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a MySQL table setup that saves only the User's best score. If they get a better score the previous score is updated.
I also want to have a 24 Hour leaderboard that only shows scores posted within the last... 24 hours.

Two options come to mind:

1) Have 2 separate tables for each leaderboard. A "Best Score" leaderboard that only saves 1 score per user and a "24 Hour" leaderboard that saves 1 score per user and is time stamped. This means every time a score is submitted it needs to be sent to 2 tables instead of 1 but the data footprint will be minimal compared to the next option.

2) Have 1 table that allows duplicate scores to be posted per-user, time stamps the scores and then simply queries the huge table of scores with the data I need (best score overall, scores within 24 hours, etc).

Any ideas/suggestions? This is the first time I've dealt with PHP/MySQL so I'm not sure what the best approach would be design/efficiency-wise.

Comment: Keep separate logics apart, so clearly go for the first design principle. It also allows to redesign/remove/change one board without having to touch the other.

Comment: Why would you do this? This is a nightmare in terms of maintaining the scores. What happens when the user decides to add another scoreboard? Then they will have to add logic in their program for this. It should all be kept at the database level, with all raw scores in a normalized state, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a normalized database, you should only have the 1 table for all scores. You should only insert, not update or delete.

Then, if you want to find the maximum score for instance, you could apply a `MAX` on the query.

If you want to find scores within the last 24 hours, you could add this into your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Plus, it has the added benefit of seeing how many games are played in total based on the amount of entries.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest have only one table that holds the best scores.

Some disadvantages of have two tables for your problem are:

- To present information perhaps you will need a join between tables (less performant that a normalized table)
- The code should be less readable and less maintainable.
- To maintain some consistency, you should work with transaction to update both.

Using only one table you should create indexes on the fields that you will use in your queries to present the 24 leaderboard. I.e: Candidates indexes will be the timestamps that will be used on the WHERE clause.

Comment: The problem with only saving the best score is that the timestamp will show the date the score was submitted, so 24 hours after you post your best time, you'll never have a score on the 24 hour leaderboard, even if you've played matches during that time.